Calibrating qubits using Qiskit Pulse with Qiskit 1.0
I am trying to implement this notebook using the updated Qiskit 1.0.
I have managed to update the code so that the job runs successfully on the IBM computer and I get the correct result.
However, there is a problem when I try to use the schedule.draw function to view the pulses.
The code sweep_schedule.draw(backend=backend) doesn't work, and I have no idea how to update it.
The full code is:
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
MY_IBM_QUANTUM_TOKEN = "XXXX"
service = QiskitRuntimeService()

print("Available backends:")
for backend in service.backends():
    print(backend.name)

backend = service.backend("ibm_kyoto")
backend_config = backend.configuration()

dt = backend_config.dt
print(f"Sampling time: {dt*1e9} ns")    # The configuration returns dt in seconds, so multiply by
                                        # 1e9 to get nanoseconds
                                        
backend.configuration().timing_constraints                                    

acquire_alignment = backend.configuration().timing_constraints['acquire_alignment']
granularity = backend.configuration().timing_constraints['granularity']
pulse_alignment = backend.configuration().timing_constraints['pulse_alignment']

import numpy as np

lcm = np.lcm(acquire_alignment, pulse_alignment)
print(f"Least common multiple of acquire_alignment and pulse_alignment: {lcm}")

backend_defaults = backend.defaults()

###### Finding the qubit Frequency using a Frequency Sweep

# unit conversion factors -> all backend properties returned in SI (Hz, sec, etc.)
GHz = 1.0e9 # Gigahertz
MHz = 1.0e6 # Megahertz
us = 1.0e-6 # Microseconds
ns = 1.0e-9 # Nanoseconds

# We will find the qubit frequency for the following qubit.
qubit = 0

# The sweep will be centered around the estimated qubit frequency.
center_frequency_Hz = backend_defaults.qubit_freq_est[qubit]        # The default frequency is given in Hz
                                                                    # warning: this will change in a future release
print(f"Qubit {qubit} has an estimated frequency of {center_frequency_Hz / GHz} GHz.")

# scale factor to remove factors of 10 from the data
scale_factor = 1e-7

# We will sweep 40 MHz around the estimated frequency
frequency_span_Hz = 40 * MHz
# in steps of 1 MHz.
frequency_step_Hz = 1 * MHz

# We will sweep 20 MHz above and 20 MHz below the estimated frequency
frequency_min = center_frequency_Hz - frequency_span_Hz / 2
frequency_max = center_frequency_Hz + frequency_span_Hz / 2
# Construct an np array of the frequencies for our experiment
frequencies_GHz = np.arange(frequency_min / GHz, 
                            frequency_max / GHz, 
                            frequency_step_Hz / GHz)

print(f"The sweep will go from {frequency_min / GHz} GHz to {frequency_max / GHz} GHz \
in steps of {frequency_step_Hz / MHz} MHz.")

def get_closest_multiple_of(value, base_number):
    return int(value + base_number/2) - (int(value + base_number/2) % base_number)

# samples need to be multiples of 16
def get_closest_multiple_of_16(num):
    return get_closest_multiple_of(num, granularity)

# Convert seconds to dt
def get_dt_from(sec):
    return get_closest_multiple_of(sec/dt, lcm)

from qiskit import pulse                  # This is where we access all of our Pulse features!
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter      # This is Parameter Class for variable parameters.
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, Gate

# Drive pulse parameters (us = microseconds)
drive_sigma_sec = 0.015 * us                           # This determines the actual width of the gaussian
drive_duration_sec = drive_sigma_sec * 8                # This is a truncating parameter, because gaussians don't have 
                                                        # a natural finite length
drive_amp = 0.05

# Create the base schedule
# Start with drive pulse acting on the drive channel
freq = Parameter('freq')
with pulse.build(backend=backend, default_alignment='sequential', name='Frequency sweep') as sweep_sched:
    drive_duration = get_closest_multiple_of_16(pulse.seconds_to_samples(drive_duration_sec))
    drive_sigma = pulse.seconds_to_samples(drive_sigma_sec)
    drive_chan = pulse.drive_channel(qubit)
    pulse.set_frequency(freq, drive_chan)
    # Drive pulse samples
    pulse.play(pulse.Gaussian(duration=drive_duration,
                              sigma=drive_sigma,
                              amp=drive_amp,
                              name='freq_sweep_excitation_pulse'), drive_chan)
    
sweep_gate = Gate("sweep", 1, [freq])

qc_sweep = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)

qc_sweep.append(sweep_gate, [0])
qc_sweep.measure(0, 0)
qc_sweep.add_calibration(sweep_gate, (0,), sweep_sched, [freq])

# Create the frequency settings for the sweep (MUST BE IN HZ)
frequencies_Hz = frequencies_GHz*GHz
exp_sweep_circs = [qc_sweep.assign_parameters({freq: f}, inplace=False) for f in frequencies_Hz]

from qiskit import schedule  
sweep_schedule = schedule(exp_sweep_circs[0],backend)

sweep_schedule.draw(backend=backend)

If I just do sweep_schedule.draw(), I get a pulse diagram, but $\Delta f$ on the graph is not correct.
